# How can i make my the user interface elements of my game adapt to the different mobile device screen in libgdx

Tags: java, user-interface, libgdx, game-development

I am working through the book "Java Game Development with libgdx by Lee Stemkoski", All the samples use the desktop to test, I am using the stage class to render actors on the android device display, but when i add actors with images, they extend out of the display of the android device i am testing on. Also, i have the same width and height set up for the desktop and mobile, but some ui elements are truncated in the desktop version but show completely in the android device. Also, do i have to design my textures with the aspect ratio of the screens i want to support in mind? e,g 16:9 screen, what kind sizes of textures should i create?.

I have tried to create a `FitViewport()` with the dimensions 800 by 480 and then add it to the stage before calling the stage act and draw methods but this does not effect any change to the game screen.

What i am trying to achieve is that i want to be able to adapt my ui elements e.g actors table textures to the display of the mobile device i am running the game on. Any help on this will be greatly appreciated!.

Answer (score 0):

The FitViewPort is the correct way to go. If it does not work, you are doing something wrong. Please share your code.